# Find nearest to now date from Dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary in this basic setup:

```
->Root
--->Monday
------->Date 1
------->Date 2
--->Tuesday
------->Date 1
------->Date 2
--->Wednesday
------->Date 1
------->Date 2
--->Thursday
------->Date 1
------->Date 2
--->Friday
------->Date 1
------->Date 2
```

How can I find, from this dictionary, the earliest date from all of these values?

Assuming that the date is changing the current value is ( `[NSDate date]`) what would I need to do to find loop through each day, the current day being the first to loop through, and find the closest date to the current date.

I hope I have made this clear. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain the structure a bit more?  Wouldn't Monday always be before Tuesday etc?  Would the physical dates be out of order of the written day string value?

Comment: Your title says earliest, your question says "nearest to now", which is it?

Comment: Also, so is your dictionary set up to be an array of dates per key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a root dictionary, with Day-of-the-week keys. Each day of the week points to an object which is a dictionary of 'Date 1' and 'Date 2' (what I'm saying does not have to be exactly what you have, this works for any structures). I'm going to use 'fast enumeration' but block enumeration can be used too.

Start off by creating a NSDate object and set it to 'now'.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

for(NSString *key1 in root) {
  NSDictionary *dates = [root objectForKey:key1];
  for(NSString *key2 in dates) {
    NSDate *otherDate = [dates objectForKey:key2];

    date = [date earlierDate:otherDate];
  }
}
```

at the end date will be the earliest date.

Comment: sorry, but could you please explain your //looping section? thanks.